# Custom Report extending another Report

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, module, url, inheritance

I used the following project and created a custom report: https://github.com/technodelight/magento_custom_reports_example

I changed stuff in the report. mainly there is another table joined to the data and the csv-export is customized.

So now I have the report at https://shop.tld/index.php/admin/admin/my_reports/index/

I now want another report that just changes the table joined to the data and the csv export.
So I need to change `\code\local\My\Reports\Model\Mysql4\Report\Collection.php` and `\code\local\My\Reports\controllers\Adminhtml\My\ReportsController.php`
I want to crate two new classes and inherit from the existing two.

What I don't know is how I have to name my classes and add them to the adminhtml.xml, so it is visible at a new menu point.

It should be available at https://shop.tld/index.php/admin/admin/my_reports/[something]/ or https://shop.tld/index.php/admin/admin/[something]/index/

The adminhtml is now

```
                <children>
                    <my_reports translate="title">
                        <title>My Custom Report</title>
                        <action>adminhtml/my_reports</action>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    </my_reports>
```

I can add another part like:

```
                    <my_report_two translate="title">
                        <title>Another Report</title>
                        <action>adminhtml/my_report_two</action>
                        <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                    </my_report_two>
```

And it will open the url https://shop.tld/index.php/admin/admin/my_report_two/index/

But there is just a 404 error, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a controller, every dash would mean a subdirectory down. So if the `adminhtml/my_reports` points to `My/ReportsController.php` , `adminhtml/my_report_two` will point to `My/Report/TwoController.php`. If this won't work, it means another thing isn't configured well.